# vb.net TextBox Cursor Position

Tags: vb.net, textbox

I am using the following code to insert a string into another string at the cursor position, and delete any selected text prior to the insert. This works if any text is selected, however if nothing is selected it fails as the code sees the position as the start of the string, wipes the entire original string and just leaves the inserted text.

All my research says all I should need to do is capture the .SelectionStart.

```
Dim str_Left, str_Right As String
Dim str_Insert as String = "Test string insert"

If (MyTextBox.SelectedText <> Nothing) Then

        'Delete any text that is selected
    MyTextBox.SelectedText = Nothing

End If

'Get cursor position in string
int_index = MyTextBox.SelectionStart

'Save string to left of cursor
str_Left = Mid(MyTextBox.Text, 1, int_index)

'Save string to right of cursor
str_Right = Mid(MyTextBox.Text, int_index + 1)

'Concatenate left string, insert field, & right string
MyTextBox.Text = str_Left & str_Insert & str_Right
```

Comment: This seems to work as expected, I just declared `int_index`  as Integer: `Dim int_index As Integer = MyTextBox.SelectionStart`

Comment: I did forget to include the declaration for int_index in my posted sample, it is declared in the actual code. Sorry.

Comment: You should update your question with all the relevant code because I am not able to reproduce the problem where it clears out the text when nothing is selected. When I try that it inserts `str_insert` wherever the cursor is and doesn't remove any other text.

Comment: That code appears to be completely pointless. If what you want to do is replace the selected text with some new text then simply assign the `String` to the `SelectedText` property. That will automatically replace any text that is currently selected. If no text is selected then it will simply insert. If you want to manually select some text beforehand, set the `SelectionStart` and `SelectionLength` properties. I don't understand why you think you need to manually delete the selected text.

Comment: The `TextBox.Text` and `TextBox.SelectedText` properties don't return `Nothing` even if you explicitly set them to `Nothing`. Both modified internally to return empty strings if so. You need to write instead `If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(MyTextBox.SelectedText) Then ...`. Also, use the [String Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=net-7.0) methods (ex. `.Replace`, `.SubString`...) instead of vb6s.

Answer (score 0):

Edited code (complete), per suggestions. Somehow I missed that it was as simple as replacing the SelectedText:

Private Sub MouseRightClick_InsertField()

```
    'Create copy of form
    Dim frm As New Settings_Report_Insert_Fields

    frm.ShowDialog()

    'Test for an Insert Feld selected
    If (frm.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then

        MyTextBox.SelectedText = "[" & frm.txt_Selected.Text & "]"

    End If

End Sub
```